# Kubernetes Persistent Volume replication

Tags: kubernetes

Manage data redundancy for stability.
I also want to duplicate the Persistent Volume.
Is there any way to replicate persistent volumes?

Answer (score 1):

Since recently the CSI interface supports snapshots.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volume-snapshots/